# Debug web client in real time

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I can inspect source and check javascript code but I was wondering how could I check what piece of code is being executed depending on the time. For example, if 5 seconds after visiting a site myfunction() is called, I want a record of this.

In other words: I want to debug/inspect in real time to know what code is being executed depending on where I click or what I do, I want to check all functions attached.

Comment: Firebug?  WebInspector?

Comment: it sounds like you want to just log events that occur.like console.log("event occurred ") and use window.setTimeout()

Comment: do console.log("Called in function 1")

Comment: project is too big and there's no time to start doing console.log now

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for this, in Chrome's developer tools for example you can go to the **Timeline** tab and hit the record button.

After you stop recording, it will show you what is being executed, the memory stack at the time, etc , etc.

Comment: Many graph bars but not even a trace of code, also I asked for real time not press record and see nothing =)

Comment: you have to press it again to stop recording, then you will see what was happening from the moment you presses record to the moment you stopped recording.

Comment: Try hitting record, doing something on the page, then pressing record again (it will be red now) to stop recording, then you will see the detail you are looking for.

Comment: It does record in real-time but you cannot use timeline to VIEW in real time because the code to generate the pretty graphs of what is happening is generated after you stop recording.

It is very robust, and if you are not willing to attach console logs or other analysis code like another user suggested, it might be your best bet.